# react map through product info and capture individual Input state as value

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pull data and map through. I am stuck at quantity bit where my state updates all quantity input values instead just the one that I am trying to increase.
How can modify this so that the when I map trough only quantity field that I change would set to that state so I can use it later to add to basket.

```
<div>
              {receivedProductsKitchen ? receivedProductsKitchen.map( products => {
                  return(
                    <div className="main-product-container" key={products.product_id}>
                        <div className="product-block-container">
                            <div className="product-name">
                                <span>{products.product_name}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="product-image-box">
                                <img src={products.product_image_url} alt={products.product_name}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="product-information">
                                <span className="product-information-drop-down">Product Information D</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="product-description">
                                <span className="product-description-text">{products.product_description}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="quantity-input-box">
                                <input id={products.product_id} type="number" placeholder="1" onChange={(e) => handleQuantity(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  );
              })
              : ''}
          </div>
```

Comment: What does `handleQuantity` do?

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem by not mapping id for the given quantity input.

My solution:

```
const handleQuantity = (e, id) =>{
       e.preventDefault();

       setQuantity({id : id, value: e.target.value});
   }
console.log(quantity)
const DisplayKitchen = () => {

       return(
         <div className="accessories-main-top-container-actions">
             <div className="accessories-main-container-all-products">
             {receivedProductsKitchen ? receivedProductsKitchen.map( products => {
                 return(
                     <div key={products.product_id}>
                   <div className="main-product-container" >
                       <div className="product-block-container" >
                           <div className="product-name">
                               <span className="product-text">{products.product_name}</span>
                           </div>
                           <div className="product-image-box">
                               <img className="product-img" src={products.product_image_url} alt={products.product_name}/>
                           </div>
                           <div className="product-information">
                               <span className="product-information-drop-down">Product Information D</span> <span className="arrow-down">{ArrowDownwardIcon}</span>
                           </div>
                           <div className="product-description">
                               <span className="product-description-text">{products.product_description}</span>
                           </div>
                           <div className="quantity-input-box">
                               <input type="number" value={quantity.id === products.product_id ? quantity.value : 1 } placeholder="1" onChange={(e) => handleQuantity(e,products.product_id)}/>
                           </div>
                           <div className="add-to-basket-container">
                               <AddToBasket />
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                     </div>
                 );
             })
             : ''}
             </div>
         </div>
       );
```

Hope it helps some one if any one got stuck :)